# Count the no of resulted rows, based on multiple slicer in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table and multiple slicers in a Dashboard. I want to take a count of how many results are showing when I select values from one/many slicers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `COUNTROWS` function in a measure:

```
MyMeasure = COUNTROWS ( MyTable )
```